# What is the difference between a model object and a entity in Spring Boot?

Tags: oop, spring-boot

A model object represents data in the MVC pattern.An entity object represents data in the ORM  pattern.I want to know differences and similarities of these two type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Entity**: An entity represents a single instance of your domain object saved into the database as a record. It has some attributes that we represent as columns in our tables.

**Model**: A model typically represents a real world object that is related to the problem or domain space. In programming, we create classes to represent objects. These classes, known as models, have some properties and methods (defining objects behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Models in MVC were originally supposed to represent the state of the UI, independent of presentation. Think of a state machine rather than just raw data. A model would encapsulate the data required for a UI, as well as any business logic required to validate and change the logical state of the UI.

Some examples:

- A timer object can serve as the model for digital and analog clock UIs.
- A list screen with add, edit and delete buttons would have a model that holds a list of items and provide methods to insert, update and remove items.
- A detail form to capture information about an entity would have a model that has the same attributes, as well as related information like possible values and user-readable text, as well as methods to validate input.

ORM is an antipattern that conflates object-oriented programming with data modeling and information systems with domain simulations. OOP is for building systems. Data modeling is for modeling knowledge. Information systems record and communicate known current and historical information. Domain simulations predict unknown information. Unfortunately, ORMs infested the MVC concept and most modern MVC frameworks have little resemblance to the original idea.

In entity-relationship modeling, an entity is any uniquely identifiable thing about which we want to store information. Entities are represented by values (not records!) in an RDBMS. Records represent facts about one or more entities. A single entity may be described by any number of records in any number of tables.